# Получить только число из переменной, содержащей текст и число

Tags: jquery, переменные

Как получить из переменной содержащей число + текст  получить только число?

P.S Формат переменно именно число, потом текст.

Comment: Заметьте, все примеры будут только при условии, что цифры идут первыми в строке.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$some = '777HappyCougar';
$num = parseInt($some); // 777
```

Comment: только вот из такой переменной: 'Happy777Cougar' вы таким способом число не получите

Comment: Спасибо, Вы совершенно правы. Будет ошибка на первом же символе и получен NaN.
Просто автор вроде указал "Формат переменно именно число, потом текст".

Comment: function parseNum(str){
      return  parseFloat(String(str).match(/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g, '') || 0, 10);
   }

Answer (score 6):

[parseInt](http://javascript.ru/parseInt)(string[, radix]) или [parseFloat](http://javascript.ru/parseInt)(string[, radix])

```
parseInt("25px", 10); // 25
parseFloat("78.12%", 10); // 78.12
```